# How to get ItemIndex of RepeaterItem from ImageButton-Click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, repeater

i want to convert this vb.net code to c#:

```
Protected Sub btnDilSil_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs)
    Dim index As Integer = CType(sender.Parent, RepeaterItem).ItemIndex
End Sub
```

i write code block below instead of the code line above but it gives error "Invalid Cast Exception", please help, thanks in advance

```
protected void btnDilSil_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    int index = ((RepeaterItem)sender).ItemIndex;
}
```

Comment: You are missing the `.Parent`, isn't it ? :)  `((RepeaterItem)sender.Parent).ItemIndex;`

Comment: i try it , but i am writing sender and  keystroke CTRL + . (dot) but it gives error it underlines Parent :(

Comment: i mean after writing sender i keystroke CTRL + .(DOT) and it gives me sender.Equals , sender.GetHashCode , sender.GetType , sender.ToString , but when i write sender.Parent , it underlines Parent

Comment: Nevermind then, as Tim said the equivalent property/access in C# seems to be  `NamingContainer`.

Comment: @JoeBilly: it's not the C# equivalent of `Parent`, you can also use that in C#(VB and C# use the same framework) but `NamingContainer` is the better approach. If the image is nested in container controls you have to use `Parent.Parent` or even `Parent.Parent.Parent` or maybe tomorrow `Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent`. That's why `NamingContainer` is more appropriate, it works always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is in the repeater you have to use it's [`NamingContainer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to get the `RepeaterItem`, that is at least the most reliable way, so better than `Parent.Parent`:

```
protected void btnDilSil_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    var img = (Control) sender;
    var item = (RepeaterItem) img.NamingContainer;
    int index = item.ItemIndex;
}
```